# Why it says "Trailing closure passed to parameter of type 'Int' that does not accept a closure"?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I added a second TabView in the SwiftUI project for Onboarding Screen, and it is throw an error like

> Trailing closure passed to a parameter of type 'Int' that does not
> accept a closure

Any idea?

```
TabView {
    ForEach(0 ..< onboardingData.count) { index in
        let element = onboardingData[index]
        OnboardingCard(onboardingItem: element)
    }
}
```

**OnboardingCard:**

```
fileprivate struct OnboardingCard: View {
    let onboardingItem: OnboardingItem
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(onboardingItem.imageName)
                .resizable()
                .frame(height: 320)
                .frame (maxWidth: .infinity)
            Text(onboardingItem.title)
                .font(.title)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .bold()
                .padding()
            Text(onboardingItem.description)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .font(.body)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                .padding (.horizontal, 15)
        }
    }
}
        
struct OnboardingItem {
    let imageName: String
    let title: String
    let description: String
}
```

Comment: Remove the space after `0`.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @mahan, tnx so much for your comment :), but still same

Comment: A bit unrelated but why an index based loop at all? Practically you don’t need the index.

Comment: wlcm. Include `onboardingData`  and `OnboardingCard` too

Comment: @vadian, I have more that imagei that is why, is there ur recommendation for it?

Comment: @mahan, still same, I do not know ehere is mistake

Comment: I mean add those too in your question.

Comment: On which line is the error occurring?

Comment: @PeterSchorn,  on here TabView line

Comment: I don't know what "TabView line" means because the TabView is on multiple lines.

Comment: @PeterSchorn, it is throw error here " VStack {
        TabView{" for TabView, it is work when I create just project for onboarding screen app, but when I integrate with existing project it is throw this error, I guess my be I have other tabview for tabbar, ı want to use first tabbar for bottom tabbar, second for onboarding screen

Comment: I just tried your code and it compiled fine. You should create a sample project on Github that doesn't compile.

Comment: @PeterSchorn, it work for me also, but when I integrate with main project, it is throw an error

Comment: Then how do you expect anyone to be able to help you if you don't post the code for the entire project? You need to share *all* of the code that is related to the error. I can't read your mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when we rename the other `TabView` like `MyTabView` in the projects, problem solved, because project do not accept two TabView with the similar name.

Answer (score 2):

I just run your code. It works as expected.

---

Confirm to the `Identifiable` protocol.

```
struct OnboardingItem: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    let imageName: String
    let title: String
    let description: String
}
```

Doing so you avoid using and index based loop. And instead do this:

```
ForEach(onboardingData) { onboardingItem in
     OnboardingCard(onboardingItem: onboardingItem)
}
```

Comment: That's not the issue here.

Comment: @mahan, it is not solve still, tnx so much for ur effort, but still do not solve problem

Comment: @Skysoft13 Could you include the code/ View that you have used `TabView` in?

Comment: @mahan, it is work in new project, but when I integrate with my existing project it is throw this error, in my existing projecy I have other Yabview also, I do not know mybe it ide due to it ?